# heroku - postgres - operator does not exist

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I decided to give heroku a try (to save time) but I discovered they use PostgreSQL which I know little about.  The [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem works great with MySQL but PostgreSQL is throwing an error.

I think this error is saying lat is not defined?

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric - character varying
LINE 1: ...58.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.358151 - lat) * P...
```

Full log

```
2011-06-07T09:18:52-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /api/v1/locations.json?point=37.358151%2C%20-121.628265%20&radius=24.374397 HTTP/1.1 | 66.192.149.18 | 963 | http | 500
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/api/v1/locations.json?point=37.358151%2C%20-121.628265%20&radius=24.374397" for 66.192.149.18 at Tue Jun 07 09:19:12 -0700 2011
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric - character varying
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...58.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.358151 - lat) * P...
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  *, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.358151 - lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(37.358151 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-121.628265 - lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance, CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(lng - -121.628265), RADIANS(lat - 37.358151))) + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing FROM "locations" WHERE (lat BETWEEN 37.0053760059938 AND 37.7109259940062 AND lng BETWEEN -122.072086383576 AND -121.184443616424) GROUP BY locations.id,locations.name,locations.bounding_box,locations.created_at,locations.updated_at,locations.street,locations.postal,locations.city,locations.state,locations.country,locations.description,locations.lat,locations.lng,locations.phone,locations.has_lights,locations.is_free,locations.is_outdoors,locations.are_pads_required,locations.has_concrete,locations.has_wood,locations.cd_page_id HAVING 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.358151 - lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(37.358151 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-121.6
2011-06-07T16:19:12+00:00 app[web.1]: 28265 - lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )) <= 24.374397 ORDER BY 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.358151 - lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(37.358151 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-121.628265 - lng) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )) ASC LIMIT 100):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it:

```
37.358151 - lat::numeric
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error.  It was caused by my specifying foreign id's in my migrations as strings instead of integers.

To fix it, I changed:

```
create_table :these_objects do |t|
  t.string:user_id
end
```

to

```
create_table :these_objects do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
end
```

Comment: SQLite never complained about it in development, but Postgres did.

Comment: SQLite's type system is pretty loose, PostgreSQL's is not. The solution is to (as you say) use proper types everywhere and ideally, develop on top of the same database that you're deploying on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
You probably have your latitude and longitude field as string, so you need to check if you lat and long fields are floats at your migration file.

```
create_table :place do |t|
  t.text :name
  t.float :latitude
  t.float :longitude
  t.timestamps
end
```